# Help with error: Failed to restart hostname.service: Unit hostname.service not found

Tags: hostname, hosts

Followed a tutorial for setting my hosts and hostname file. When I go to `service hostname restart` I get error:

`Failed to restart hostname.service: Unit hostname.service not found.`

My hosts file is set up like this:

127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.1.1 bobsrevenge.com bob

My hostname file is like this:

bob

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? it sounds like the tutorial may not be appropriate for your version

Comment: @steeldriver ubuntu server 22.04.2 LTS. I got another related question, maybe I should edit my original one, if my domain name is bobsrevenge.com, my server is named bob, would I put `127.0.1.1 bob.bobsrevenge.com bob`?